# How to define the first column as names in pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I fail to read/insert the first column of csv file, I have already set the names in the csv file, although, if I type as name=['...','...' etc], python will set them again, and I will end up having the names 2 times, I want to implement the data from the csv into names of pd.read_csv.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import tkFileDialog
    import numpy as np
    import warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

    rating=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_csv(rating, sep='\t')
    print df.head()


    movies=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    movie_titles=pd.read_csv(movies)
    print movie_titles.head

    df=pd.merge(df,movies,on='movieId')
    print df.head()
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/MP2/test panda.py", line 16, in <module>
    df=pd.merge(df,movies,on='movieId')
  File "C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\MP2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 47, in merge
    validate=validate)
  File "C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\MP2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 480, in __init__
    right = validate_operand(right)
  File "C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\MP2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1752, in validate_operand
    'a {obj} was passed'.format(obj=type(obj)))
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <type 'unicode'> was passed
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(rating, sep='\t', header=None, skiprows=1, names=[...])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood what you want to do, but as I can see, there are three possible issues there:

1. `df` is incorrectly trying to merge itself;
2. `merge` generating duplicated columns (and values);
3. `merge` trying to work with `unicode`;

The first issue is an error. Your variable `df` is trying to merge itself to another one (`movie_titles`) but the syntax is not correct.

Try this, instead:

```py
df = df.merge(movie_titles, on='movieId')
```

The second issue is not a problem: it is default, actually. When you merge two datasets with same column headers, you get `header_x` and `header_y`.

For instance:

```
    header1_x    header2_x    header1_y    header2_y
0           a            f            a            f
1           b            g            b            g
2           c            h            c            h
3           d            i            d            i
```

One way of solving it --one that is not going to take you too much thinking-- is dropping the columns you do not want:

```py
df = df[[header1_x, header2_x]]
```

The third issue is related to `unicode` object. It means the header `movieId` probably is not encoded correctly.

If it persists after you work on the previous issues, try `unicodedata` (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unicodedata.html)):

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", df).encode("ascii',"ignore')
```

Answer (score 2):

The following line:

```
df=pd.merge(df, movies, on='movieId')
```

Should be:

```
df=pd.merge(df, movie_titles, on='movieId')
```

The `movies` variable contains a string, not a dataframe.